# Output factorials with while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is supposed to take an input and then output the factorials up to the inputted number

For example, if the input is 8 the output would be 1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320.

I thought I had the right functions set up for this, however I just get an infinite loop of negatives.

```
limit=input('enter a value for limit:')
limit=int(limit)
ctr=0
factorial=1
while ctr < (limit):
    print (ctr, end=' ')
    factorial=factorial*ctr
    ctr=ctr-1
print("limit =", limit)
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah, ctr=ctr+1 just adds 0,1,2,3... up to whatever the input is

Comment: 1. Print `factorial` instead of `ctr`, 2. use `ctr = ctr+1`, 3. factorial will always be 0 in this code

Comment: @tigerhawkt3 so replacing print(ctr, end=' ') but ctr with factorial?

Comment: @JulienSpronck whats wrong with my code then if its going to be 0 every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are wrong in this code:

1. why are you printing the counter `ctr` and not `factorial`?
2. ctr needs to be incremented by 1 and not decremented: `ctr = ctr + 1`
3. In your code, `factorial` will be 0 since you multiply factorial by 0 at the first iteration.

Here's a code that should work:

```
limit=input('enter a value for limit:')
limit=int(limit)
ctr=1
factorial=1
while ctr <= limit:
    factorial=factorial*ctr
    print (factorial, end=' ')
    ctr=ctr+1
```